# Is there a workaround for `npm publish -f`

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

Now that `npm publish -f` is deprecated, is there a workaround or a package that makes it possible to **overwrite** a target version after it's been published?

I know about [semver](http://semver.org/); I still want `npm publish -f`.

Comment: I read about `npm unpublish`, but it doesn't seem to always work... since I can't seem to publish the same version after unpublishing it.

Comment: "[*Even if a package version is unpublished, that specific name and version combination can never be reused. In order to publish the package again, a new version number must be used.*](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/unpublish)" So, I would say no, there probably isn't an alternative to replace a particular version once it's been published.

Comment: There seems to be a direct correlation between the popularity of Bitcoin and Ethereum and the growing number of companies that ship their software with immutability in mind

Comment: @PaulBerg So are you saying that Bitcoin/Ethereum are to blame for this fad?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

someone said this on npm's github issue:

> @nmrony You cannot overwrite previously-published packages anymore (since February 2014, if I recall correctly).

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8305#issuecomment-236412989

Comment: Is there no way to do this with snapshots? Like a maven style publish that lets you accumulate snapshots of the same version in the repo

Answer (score 38):

You can unpublish a specific version, and then republish it:

```
npm unpublish myModule@1.2.3
```

And then republish the version.

This works if the module is hosted on your own npm repo, but for `registry.npmjs.org`, you won't be able to reuse the version number after unpublishing, and there's a time-limit (72 hours) after which you can no longer unpublish. See the [npm Unpublish Policy](https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish).

Comment: warning if you do this for the only published version then you will need to wait 24hrs before publishing again

Answer (score 11):

According to [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/unpublishing-packages-from-the-registry#when-to-unpublish) this unpublished versions cannot be republished,bump a patch version and publish

> *Once a package is unpublished, it cannot be republished. If you’ve unpublished a package by mistake, we’d recommend publishing again under a different name, or for unpublished versions, bumping the version number and publishing again.*

So:

```
npm unpublish
npm version patch
npm publish
```

will do the job.

Comment: I was looking for `npm version patch` because I wrote a module to publish modules for me.

Comment: `npm version patch` will not read actual version from remote. It will increment to what value is available on local. So, to get info from remote, do: `npm info MODULE-NAME`.

Comment: This makes sense from a security perspective.

Answer (score 9):

This will probably not be viable but there's an overkill method

`npm unpublish --force` - will delete your entire project

wait 24 hours

`npm publish`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue.I published a new package with new version but same content.

```
npm publish --access public (version - 0.1.1)
```

Now, delete the original package.

```
npm unpublish -f package_name@0.1.0
```

wait 24 hours republish the original package & delete the new package.

```
npm publish --access public (version - 0.1.0)
npm unpublish -f package_name@0.1.1
```

Your package user will not find original version for 24 hours, so package manager will show drop down to choose other version & most will go with latest version.